# What happened with CEILING() SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today, I found a bug with `CEILING()`. I don't know why.

Who can give me an answer, pls.

Thanks.

When I test CEILING() SQL Server 2012:

[image]

Comment: you are using FLOAT. Float is approximate value. Change to decimal and try

Comment: On top it seemswhile you can fid a bug, you never actually bothered learning how to make a bug report. What are we looking at? Where you THINK is the error? WHat you think should be the correct value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Just for reference, https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug *per se*. A floating point cannot represent `0.17` exactly, since it cannot be represented as a finite sum of (negative) powers of `2`. Therefore `0.17` is represented by the closest representable number.

As a result `0.17` is actually represented as something like `0.170000...1`. Therefore performing `CEILING` will represent it as `1701`.

As @Squirrel says, you can use a [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) which stores a number exactly for a given amount of digits.